# How to check if every range of a dataframe series between 2 values has another value

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas Dataframe I have 1 series A

```
Index  A

0      2
1      1
2      6
3      3
4      2
5      7
6      1
7      3
8      8
9      1
10     3
```

I would like to check if between every 1 of column A there is a number 2 and to write in column B the results like this:

```
Index  A    B

0      2   FALSE
1      1   FALSE
2      6   FALSE
3      3   FALSE
4      2   TRUE
5      7   FALSE
6      1   FALSE
7      3   FALSE
8      2   TRUE
9      1   FALSE
10     3   FALSE
```

I though to use rolling() as a function, but can rolling work with a random sized window of values (ranges) ?

Comment: What would happen if there were multiple 2s between 1s would they all be true?

Comment: the first would be enough. but if there is also a second true tha would be not a problem

Comment: Okay. Then, the way I'm seeing this question is "How do I set every 2 after the first 1 to `True`?" Is there some additional logic I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic and straightforward way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({"A":[2,1,6,3,2,7,1,3,2,1,3]})

for i, cell in enumerate(df["A"]):
    if (1 in list(df.loc[:i,"A"])) and (1 in list(df.loc[i:,"A"])) and cell==2:
        df.at[i,"B"] = True
    else:
        df.at[i,"B"] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = (df["A"] == 1) | (df["A"] == 2)
df = df.assign(B=df.loc[mask, "A"].sub(df.loc[mask, "A"].shift()).eq(1)).fillna(False)
```

```
>>> df
    A      B
0   2  False
1   1  False
2   6  False
3   3  False
4   2   True
5   7  False
6   1  False
7   3  False
8   2   True
9   1  False
10  3  False
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) to assign 2s in 'A' to `True` after the first 1 is found:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['A'].eq(1).cumsum().ge(1) & df['A'].eq(2), True, False)
```

`df`:

```
    A      B
0   2  False
1   1  False
2   6  False
3   3  False
4   2   True
5   7  False
6   1  False
7   3  False
8   2   True
9   1  False
10  3  False
```

---

Imports and DataFrame used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1, 6, 3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3]})
```